# insert and select strings array from database.?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want all strings array insert in a row the database, and after that, elsewhere select only the **first part** of they(strings array) And displaying they(first part strings array) by loop foreach.

What function do I do [`serialized` or `implode` or `json_encode` or `?` ]? Did you can give me an example?

**EXAMPLE:**
data(strings array):

> 1. "input name='units[]'" = value => hello, how, where
> 2. "input name='units[]'" = value => hi, what, other

I want this output:

> - hello
> - hi

Comment: Your question (if it is one) is very difficult to understand. What specifically are you looking for? Are you trying to insert an array into a DB table field?

Comment: yes, i want array value `1` & `2` in above post and select only the first part -> `select * form table name ...` output like(in above post) -> (`hello`, `hi`).

Comment: Do you know, I'm feeling [a strange sense of deja vu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276289/insert-serialized-string)...

Comment: [Déjà-vu: possible duplicate of "unserialize only first part?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275777/unserialize-only-first-part)

Comment: Answer mr @cwallenpoole is same thing that i want. According to the answer he what is your proposal for CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is normally using 'implode' and loop using `while` and one of the mysql_fetch functions:

```
$units = $_REQUEST['units'];
$units = array_map( 'mysql_real_escape_string', $units );
mysql_query( "INSERT INTO <table name> VALUES('" . 
    implode("'),('", $units)."')" );
```

Then:

```
$q = mysql_query( 'select * from <table name>' );
while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $q ) )
{
   echo $row[0];
}
```

Sometimes, however, `serialize` is the better choice:

```
$units = $_REQUEST['units'];
$units = array_map( 'mysql_real_escape_string', $units );
mysql_query( "INSERT INTO <table name> VALUES('" . 
    serialize($units)."')" );
```

Then:

```
$q = mysql_query( 'select * from <table name>' );
while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $q ) )
{
   $units = unserialize( $row[0] );
}
var_dump($units); // use foreach here.
```